# innerText has new line though innerHTML have no explicit new line, tab, or <br> <p>

Tags: javascript, html, css

My goal is to give each character a different css characteristics but it still keeps its form as a word, using chrome extension.

The original element was

```
Art info
```

Using chrome extension, I wrapped each character with span.

```
<span wms-wrap>
<span>A</span>
<span>r</span>
<span>t</span>
 <span>i</span>
<span>n</span>
<span>f</span>
<span>o</span>
</span>
```

I checked its innerHTML in chrome by and it shows
$0.innerHTML

```
<span>A</span><span>r</span><span>t</span> <span>i</span><span>n</span><span>f</span><span>o</span>
```

This is exactly what I wanted.

When I checked its innerText in chrome, however, it shows that

```
$0.innerText
"A
R
T
I
C
L
E
I
N
F
O"
```

It was found that new line is inserted between every spans.

I searched web and applied some advices such as nobr tag and  <style="white-space: nowrap;"> but still new lines are added.

How can I prevent these unexpected new lines?

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/). We can't help you with code, HTML, and CSS we can't see. :-)

Comment: Is removing the linebreaks between `</span>` and `<span>` an option?

Comment: Can you confirm `<span wms-wrap>` is correct, please? Isn't `wms-wrap` the value of some (custom) attribute?

Comment: @Sebastian Simon Yes removing the linebreaks between span are acceptable

Comment: @secan you are right.   the correct code is <span class="wms-wrap">

Answer (score 2):

The newlines are there because they're there in your source code. Whitespace is collapsed for *display*, which can be influenced by CSS, but you are looking at the DOM, which is the *input* to that display logic, so needs to retain the original whitespace.

You can either change your source code not to have newlines, or strip them later with a JavaScript string.replace call. Since you don't show much of your code, it's hard to be more specific than that.

On the other hand, if the important thing is how it *looks*, don't worry too much about the DOM.